# ask whether there is an agent in a Queue or not (AnyLogic Simulation)

Tags: java, queue, simulation, anylogic

I want to write a function in AnyLogic that returns TRUE if there is an agent in the Queue

I don`t know what function should I use.

```
if( VIP_Female_Queue." some function that returns true if there is an agent")
{
...
};
```

I tried to use capacity and contain but it didn`t work.

please Help!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is simple... to know the number of agents in a queue, you can use the size() method which is present in almost all the PML blocks... in your case you just need to use the following code:

```
if(VIP_Female_Queue.size()>0){
    ...
}
```

If you want to know if a particular agent is in the queue... you can do:

```
if(agent.currentBlock().equals(VIP_Female_Queue)){
    ...
}
```

Comment: Please describe in your answer, what was the problem, and how will this snippet solve it, to help others understand this answer